# How can i turn my nuxt universal app to mobile native app

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js, vue-native

i already made couple of **Nuxt** RND (**universal and spa**) application.
Now i want to turn those application into native mobile app.
Vue native is one option,but i just want keep everything in a shape with SSR mode

Please give me your valuable suggestions

Thanks Everyone, 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also take a look at [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/#adding-capacitor-to-an-existing-web-app) by Ionic, which enables you to build Hybrid apps. It will basically take your built UI, bundle that inside generated native apps and render it through [WebView](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/webview). After you install Capacitor and run `npx cap init` you might need to set the directory of your built web assets inside `capacitor.config.json` to `"webDir": "dist"`.